# Nodemailer error handling (Node.js) doesn't work as intended. Email still goes through even though **name inputfield** is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

On the front-end (React) I can do error handling, however, I want to implement error handling on the back-end (Node.js) too. I thought I can do it at the **transporter.sendMail** but it doesn't work. It still sends the email through Nodemailer **when the name inputfield is empty**. What did I miss?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');
const creds = require('./config');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
    const htmlEmail = `
            Name: ${req.body.name}
            Phone: ${req.body.phone}
            Email: ${req.body.email}
        `;

    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.name,
        to: 'MYEMAIL',
        subject: 'example message subject',
        html: htmlEmail,
    };

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
        port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: 'MYEMAIL',
            pass: 'MYPASSWORD',
        },
    });

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
        if (err || req.body.name.length === 0) {
            res.json({
                status: 'fail',
            });
            console.log('Message could not be sent.');
            return null;
        } else {
            res.json({
                status: 'success',
            });
            console.log('Message sent.');
        }
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the req.body first before doing any kind of operation. Just like the following.

```
app.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.name.trim().length === 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: "Name is required"});
    }
    .........
```

Comment: Why do I need the trim?

Comment: trim will remove all the extra white spaces if there is any. Suppose user only enters three spaces and no text. So, if you are only checking the length then your username will be three space "   "